# Cannot generate view binder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I don't know how to solve the problem

Run time error i'm getting in android studio

```
error: cannot generate view binders java.lang.ClassCastException: android.databinding.tool.expr.StaticIdentifierExpr cannot be cast to android.databinding.tool.expr.ViewFieldExpr
```

My Code

```
class EditProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {


    fun onEditProfileInfoListner(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(view.context, EditProfileInfoActivity::class.java)
        view.context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Activity file

```
class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityEditProfileBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_edit_profile)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EditProfileViewModel::class.java)
        binding.editProfileViewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

My XML file

```
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable name="EditProfileViewModel" type="com.crushmeet.ui.profile.EditProfileViewModel"/>
    </data>
```

I tried invalidate cache, Clean Project, Rebuild it,
Also tried to delete files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you get a `ClassCastException`

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

An example of binding that you can follow:

**XML**

```
 <data>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.example.databinding.MainViewModel" />
</data>
```

**Activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

    val binding: ActivityMainBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.viewmodel = vm
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
}
```